# Initializing an IBOutlet with a designated initializer? (Using storyboard)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, designated-initializer

is it possible to initialize an IBOutlet of a custom UIView type with a designated initializer (using storyboard)? If yes when and how should the initialization in the UIViewController occur.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you load something from a storyboard, it will call `initWithCoder:`, which you can implement for your custom class.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah I thought about initWithCoder. But I don't know what is better to implement this in the UIView or UIViewController. This shouldn't be a double thread I'm sry for. But the basis of my question is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23030891/initialization-of-a-custom-uiview-in-a-uiviewcontroller-using-a-storyboard